# Read all dynamic name and value from JSON string

Tags: c#, json

I need to get all dynamic name and values from JSON string. I am going to create one function with JSON string parameter. that parameter JSON string name and values can change, But I need to print all names and values from that JSON string.

Example  code :

```
json : {   "data": 
       [{
         "id": "001",
         "Name": "Somu",
         "Address": "Erode",
        },
        {
         "id": "002",
         "Name": "Ajal",
         "Address": "USA",
        }]
       }
```

I want to Get all values from this JSON with in loop. Property name may change or increase property count.I need to get all values from passed JSON.

```
 Expected Result :  1 st loop
            Id = 001
            Name =Somu
            Address =Erode
         2 nd loop
            Id = 002
            Name =Ajal
            Address =USA
```

Comment: what serializer are you using? or do you have flexibility to use any? IIRC this is a lot easier in, say, json.net - than via things like JavaScriptSerializer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/)

```
string json = @"{ ""data"": [ { ""id"": ""001"", ""Name"": ""Somu"", ""Address"": ""Erode"", }, { ""id"": ""002"", ""Name"": ""Ajal"", ""Address"": ""USA"", }] }";

var result  = JObject.Parse(json)
                ["data"]
                .Select(x => new
                {
                    id = (string)x["id"],
                    Name = (string)x["Name"],
                    Address = (string)x["Address"],
                })
                .ToList();
```

or more dynamic versions

```
var result  = JObject.Parse(json)
                ["data"]
                .Select(x=> x.Children().Cast<JProperty>()
                             .ToDictionary(p=>p.Name,p=>(string)p.Value))
                .ToList();
```

.

```
var result = JObject.Parse(json)["data"]
                    .ToObject<List<Dictionary<string,string>>>();
```

Comment: Second one only i expected. How can read result values through loop